# Should we use singular or plural after questions asking “Which among the following ...”?

Tags: grammatical-number, questions, verb-agreement

Should I use singular or plural after a question starting with *Which among the following*?

For example, should it be version #1 or version #2 below?

1. Which among the following **statements** are ...?
2. Which among the following **statement** is ...?

Where the reader is supposed to make a selection from a set of several possible statements listed below that question.

Comment: Are they allowed to choose more than one true statement?

Comment: @Cascabel No, just one

Comment: *Which among the following **is** the [one and only] correct **answer**?* OR *Which among the following **are** the [by implication, multiple] incorrect **answers**?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers 'is' the one and only.

Comment: If you know that, why did you ask?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Which of the following cars is the best? or Which of the following car is the best? I know which verb to use, but I was confused to which word to use with the verb.

Comment: You may be confusing the question with the answer. You already know you are offering statements. Even if you allow for choosing several true statements from the statements you offer, your choices are plural. Also, it may help you to see that *which* represents *which one* or *which ones* out of the statements.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Do please note that the asker’s peculiar phrasing ❌   *Which among the following...* is [not how this question is “ever” asked in actual English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=which+of+the+following%2C+which+among+the+following&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwhich%20of%20the%20following%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhich%20among%20the%20following%3B%2Cc0). It’s at best a non-native-speaker formulation to use *among* here in lieu of a simple *of* for such questions.

Comment: @tchrist: Agreed, ***among*** isn't very idiomatic compared to ***of*** in this context. That's not relevant to the thing being asked about here (is it a singular or plural noun in *one of/among [several] **X / Xs***). But it ***is*** something the OP could usefully take on board - and it's things like that which I think sit more naturally on ELL than ELU, so the question is well migrated, imho.

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to give one correct answer then the word 'which' is referring to the correct answer among all the statements, and so the subject of the sentence is singular, so it will get a singular verb, so ' is ' is correct,